# Why can't I retrieve objects from Parse and store in an array?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I want to retrieve these objects and store them in an array.

When I print inside the function, everything works fine. However, printing outside, the arrays are empty.

I've tried without the function and followed an answer on Stack Overflow but still no idea what's going on.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    func getAllInfoFromParse () {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"UserQRCodes")
            query.whereKey("userName", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (results, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else if let results = results {
                    for object in results {
                        if let userInfo = object["info"] as? String {

                            self.infoTakenFromUsersParse.append(userInfo)
                            print(self.infoTakenFromUsersParse)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    getAllInfoFromParse ()
    print(self.infoTakenFromUsersParse)
    self.infoTakenFromUsersParseWithoutDups = self.infoTakenFromUsersParse.removingDuplicates()
    print("The info from parse is here \(self.infoTakenFromUsersParseWithoutDups)")
    print("The info from parse is here \(self.infoTakenFromUsersParse)")
    print(self.imageFiles)
    print(imageFiles)
    print(imageFiles)

Console:

logged in
[]
The info from parse is here []
The info from parse is here []
[]
[]
[]
[]
["Coffee Shop"]
```

The array is to populate a tableView. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also....the function is in viewDidLoad. The array is written as var infoTakenFromUsersParse: [String] = []

Comment: What's the structure of the "info" dictionary that you are retrieving?

Comment: Its a Parse colomn of strings called "info"

Comment: maybe if your have your code on some repo I can take a look, since I can't point any error here

Comment: Im a beginner, but from everything I've learnt this is really confusing me as it should work. Not sure what to do from here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query for each individual item again. Those objects should be in the original response. You also need to make sure that the username that you are querying for on line 3 is for the actual user's username and not the actual user object. Lastly, based on your comments, it appears that you need some kind of callback function to tell when the request has finished executing so add that to the `getInfoFromParse` function. Try something like this:

```
func getInfoFromParse(callback: () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"UserQRCodes")
    query.whereKey("userName", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (results, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let results = results {
            for object in results {
                if let userInfo = object["info"] as? String {
                    self.infoTakenFromUsersParse.append(userInfo)
                }
            }
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
            callback()
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Then, when you're ready to access the results of this function do something like this:

```
getInfoFromParse {
    print(self.infoTakenFromUsersParse)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cole, this was my original code, when the arrays weren't updating I thought id change it. Ive changed it back to this one but the console still prints them as empty. It prints them all INSIDE the function though...

Comment: To be clear, is the info property a String or is it a pointer?

Comment: And there is a column in the `UserQRCodes` class in parse called `userName` and it is also a string? Because, in the example you provided you were comparing the `userName` column against the entire user object. That will almost certainly not work if I'm understanding your configuration correctly.

Comment: ah!.. the UserName column has "Pointer <_User>" in it. What have I don't wrong here?

Comment: Then you had it right in your original answer. I updated my answer. I believe this snippet should work but if not, the only way I can help you debug from here is if you can tell me what the results of the query are. Set a breakpoint or add some logs to see what you're getting.

Comment: If I were you, I would name that column something other than userName though. That could be confusing to your future self or any other devs that look at this.

Comment: The reason its a pointer is because in the next ViewController (QRScanner) when it scans the QR it matches it to one saved in Parse. If it does match then it saves it to parse using PFUser.current() At first I thought it was my code linking to Parse that was the problem, but it prints everything I want inside the function..... just not outside.

Comment: I would suggest adding the code that you're talking about to the question so we can get a better idea of what you mean when you say "...just not outside."

Comment: Ok, Ive edited the main problem... with the console prints below. The first two Empty Strings are above the function, ignore them.

Comment: Oh it's not printing it the console because the request is asynchronous and by the time you call print(self.infoTakenFromUsersParse), the request is not done loading. You need to implement some kind of callback function. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Sorry same result.